# Overlay grid onto QFrame

Tags: qt, qgridlayout, qframe

So, I have a `QFrame` with its layout set as a `QGridLayout`.

Within this layout I have tiles in rows of 16 which represent something of a palette.

I want this grid of tiles to be separated by lines, like a grid should be. I can do this easily with the tiles' `paintEvent`s.

[image]

However, the obvious problem is that between the tiles, the lines are doubled up. When I scale this up for other applications, the difference becomes even more noticeable.

So, is there a way to create a gridline overlay for my `QFrame`? I have considered converting the whole thing to a view/scene solution, and using `drawForeground`, however this seems like a completely inappropriate use of the paradigm.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `QFrame` into a `QGridLayout`, then put a custom `QWidget` with transparent background and `paintEvent` that paints the grid on top of it (same `QGridLayout` position).

Or since you already have a `QGridLayout`, just put the custom `QWidget` in that, above the tiles, [filling the entire grid](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2).

---

A side note, are you sure you want `QFrame` there, or if just `QWidget` would do? Just saying, because with `QFrame` you get that 1990's look into your UI... If you do want that then go ahead, just saying.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually ended up falling rear-end backwards into the solution: create a custom QWidget with the grid drawing paintEvent as you described, and setting its parent as the QFrame. As long as I instantiate it after my tiles, it overlays them perfectly. As for the QFrame aesthetics, I guess I really don't mind

Comment: Changed to your second solution, via grid-filling. Makes the overlay portable with the grid itself, as adding anything above the grid moves the grid's contents but not the overlay with my previous solution.

Comment: @ConnorSpangler Yeah, it's usually best to try and get things working with Qt layouts, and resort to other solutions (like overriding resizeEvent) only if you need something special which Qt layouts can't do.